# Comparing attribute values in xsd in WSDL

Tags: java, soap, xsd, wsdl

i have 2 attributes called rowstart and rowend.

so when i am writing xsd i need to have a condition like rowstart < rowend.

is there any way to do that in XSD. ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in simple XSD. At least, I did not find any mention of this in the XSD definition.
See also http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp